# Show div outside a scrollable parent element

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I want to show a div above his parent element which is scrollable (overflow: scroll) and relative positioned (position: relative). Any ideas? Thank you very much!

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative; /* position: static is not an option */
}
span{
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you don't want the yellow to be affected by the scroll?

Comment: the child element gets clipped by container with overflow: scroll